# ¿Actualizar un listado de laravel con ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-5

tengo un listado de áreas cuyo código luce así:

```
<table class="table table-responsive-lg table-striped table-borderless mb-4 mt-2"> 
                        <tr class="verde-t">
                            <th>@lang('Name')</th>
                            <th>@lang('Tag')</th>
                            <th>@lang('Plant')</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>

                        @forelse($areas as $area)

                        <tr class="text-white">
                            <td> {{ $area->name }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $area->tag }} </td>
                            <td> {{ $area->plant->name }} </td>
                            <td class="p-1 align-middle">
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <a href="{{ route('areas.show', $area) }}" class="btn btn-sm verde-b text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="@lang('View')"><i class="material-icons mic">visibility</i></a> &nbsp 

                                             @if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole(['admin', 'user1']))
                                    <a href="{{ route('areas.edit', $area) }}" class="btn btn-sm verde-b text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="@lang('Edit')"><i class="material-icons mic">edit</i></a> &nbsp 
                                             @elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('user2'))
                                    <a href="{{ route('areas.edit', $area) }}" class="btn btn-sm verde-b text-white disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="@lang('Edit')"><i class="material-icons mic">edit</i></a> &nbsp 
                                            @endif

                                             @if(Auth::user()->hasAnyRole(['admin', 'user1']))
                                    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmDeletion">
                                        <button id="{{ 'delete-button-'.$loop->index }}" class="btn btn-sm verde-b text-white" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="@lang('Delete')" onclick=""><i class="material-icons mic">delete</i></button>
                                    </span>
                                             @elseif(Auth::user()->hasRole('user2'))
                                    <span>
                                        <button id="{{ 'delete-button-'.$loop->index }}" class="btn btn-sm verde-b text-white disabled" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="@lang('Delete')"><i class="material-icons mic">delete</i></button>
                                            @endif
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        var ruta = {!! json_encode(route('areas.destroy', $area), JSON_HEX_TAG) !!};
                                        document.getElementById("{{ 'delete-button-'.$loop->index }}").setAttribute("onclick", "actionSwitch('" + String(ruta) + "');");
                                    </script>

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        @empty
                        <tr class="text-white">
                            <td style="display: inline-block;"> @lang('There are no areas to show.') </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforelse

                    </table>
```

Y tengo un filtro por plantas que funciona correctamente, el problema es que hay que hacer click en un botón "filtrar" para que funcione, me gustaría eliminar eso, y estoy intentando hacerlo con ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var plantSelect = $('#plant_id');
    plantSelect.change(function(){
        var plantId = $(this).val();
        if (plantId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('areas.index') }}",
                type: 'GET',
                data: { plant_id: plantId },
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log('Se ha registrado el cambio');
                    //Acá no se que hacer
                },
                error : function(){
                    alert('Hubo un error obteniendo las areas!');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Podrías incluir un ejemplo de `response` ? a partir de ese dato entiendo que tienes que volver a armar la tabla o actualizarla.

Comment: La respuesta devuelve un listado de objetos "área".  Simplemente recorro @forelse($areas as $area) y acceso a los datos de cada área (name, plant->name, tag)